# ON DELETE SET DEFAULT - unimplemented feature

Tags: sql, oracle

While creating  table .

A error messege is showing `SQL Error: ORA-03001: unimplemented feature`

```
CREATE TABLE OrgChart
  (
    job_title VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    emp_nbr   INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL REFERENCES Personnel(emp_nbr) ON
  DELETE SET DEFAULT ON
  UPDATE CASCADE,
    boss_emp_nbr INTEGER REFERENCES Personnel(emp_nbr),
    UNIQUE (emp_nbr, boss_emp_nbr),
    salary DECIMAL (12,4) NOT NULL CHECK (salary >= 0.00)
  );
```

How do I declare a foreign key that allows updates to cascade from the parent table and that sets the value to the default (0 in this case) when the parent row is deleted?

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Question is ... why it is saying unimplemented feature.. in oracle doc it is proper syntax `http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.5-en/create-table-foreign-keys.html`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oracle does not support cascading updates.  It also does not allow you to set the value to the default when the parent row is deleted.  Your two options for an `on delete` behavior are `cascade` or `set null`.  Obviously, it wouldn't make sense to define a `set null` behavior if you want the column to be declared `not null`.

In general, primary keys ought to be immutable.  You shouldn't generally be declaring a column as a primary key if you intend to allow it to be updated.  If `emp_nbr` needs to change (which seems odd), you probably want a different primary key.  It also strikes me as odd that you'd want an employee to remain in the `OrgChart` table if the employee has been removed.  If you want to allow an org chart to have a spot with no employee, you'd probably want to allow `emp_nbr` to be nullable in `OrgChart` and declare the foreign key to be `on delete set null`.