# ORA missing right parenthesis and unimplemented feature

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying to execute the following script on Oracle APEX:

```
CREATE TABLE employer (
    ename       VARCHAR2(30)     NOT NULL,
    essn        CHAR(9),
    bdate       DATE,
    dno         INTEGER     DEFAULT 1
        CHECK (dno > 0 AND dno < 21),
    superssn    CHAR(9),
    CONSTRAINT employer_pk
        PRIMARY KEY (essn),
    CONSTRAINT employer_fk
        FOREIGN KEY (superssn) REFERENCES employer (essn)
            ON DELETE SET NULL
            ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE department (
    dname           VARCHAR2(10)     NOT NULL,
    dnumber         INTEGER         NOT NULL,
    mgrssn          CHAR(9)         NOT NULL,
    mgrstartdate    CHAR(9)         NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (dnumber),
    UNIQUE (dname),
    FOREIGN KEY (mgrssn) REFERENCES employer (essn)
        ON DELETE SET DEFAULT
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

However, it gives 2 errors. ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis on the first table, and ORA-03001: unimplemented feature on the second.

When I tried to run the script without the `ON DELETE`/`ON UPDATE` statements, it didn't show any errors and the tables were created successfully. Do I need a parenthesis somewhere when I'm adding `ON DELETE`/`ON UPDATE`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ON DELETE SET DEFAULT - unimplemented feature](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102957/on-delete-set-default-unimplemented-feature)

Comment: FYI: after answering your question, I noticed it is a duplicate. I voted to close it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle doesn't support the following features:

`ON UPDATE CASCADE`

`ON DELETE SET DEFAULT`

Presumably, your script will run fine if you remove them. Personally, I've never needed either of them (since I always use surrogate primary keys that are never changed).

Comment: You're right, it works fine after removing `ON UPDATE CASCADE` and changing `ON DELETE` to `SET NULL`. Thanks, I didn't know that Oracle didn't support those features.